# Do we have a AWS Named Profile like functionality in Google Cloud?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, cloud, profile, gsutil

I want to know whether Google Cloud provides AWS Named Profile like functionality i.e. I want to pass the credentials to the Google Cloud’s gsutil commands at run time.

For example, in the below scenario, I want to pass different configurations/credentials while coping data(using gsutil) in two different Google Cloud Buckets.

--Google Cloud (Not working Scenario for GCP)

```
gsutil cp -r C:/Users/Downloads/crm.txt gs://bucket_crm_123 --configuration=config1
gsutil cp -r C:/Users/Downloads/payroll.txt gs://bucket_payroll_123 --configuration=config2
```

--AWS  (Working Scenario for AWS)

```
aws s3 cp C:/Users/Desktop/GCFR/testfiles/ s3://hive1s3/ --profile User1 --recursive

aws s3 cp C:/Users/Desktop/GCFR/testfiles1/ s3://hive2s3/ --profile User2--recursive
```

So in a nutshell, I want to make sure that a user/configuration can only access the Google Cloud bucket if he has privileges on it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want flag like "run as" function??

If yes, You can do same work with "service account".

Create service accounts with appropriate permissions.(permissions that can access a bucket you want)

And add -i flag in your gsutil command with a service account you made.

Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions#options) to get more information about -i flag.

Or if you must specify a user, You can change user that runs command with command below.

> gcloud config set account USERACCOUNT

Run gsutil command after changing user account via this command.

*Plus)* You must enroll user accounts you use for gsutil before run "gcloud config set account" command.

Run command "gcloud auth login" and authenticate user account.

Only user accounts registered with this process can be used.

If you want to know what user accounts can be use, run "gcloud auth list" command.

Comment: Thanks but I am getting the below error while using a user-created service account.    Command  : gsutil -i crm-srv-acc@propane-calling-272510.iam.gserviceaccount.com ls    Error : "AccessDeniedException: Service account impersonation failed. Please go to the Google Cloud Platform Console (https://cloud.google.com/console), select IAM & admin, then Service Accounts, and grant your originating account the Service Account Token Creator role on the target service account."

Comment: Seems that you don't have permssion that use service account.. Grant your account a proper permission or Go plan B